# NoClassDefFoundError when runnung on server using apache commons httpclient lib

Tags: java, apache, jboss, wildfly-8, apache-commons-httpclient

i'm writing a dynamic-web-project with wildfly as my web-server by java
in this project, i want to connect with other server
the library i'm using is apache.commons
however, the function works when i run as application
but once i run as server, it comes out an exception, NoClassDefFoundError, pointing at the line i new the object
( ConnectUtil util = new ConnectUtil() ) <- line of error triggered
i have tried to import the .jar below but still not working

comments-codec-1.10

comments-fileupload-1.3.1

comments-httpclient-3.1

comments-io-2.4

comments-lang-2.6

comments-logging-1.2

comments-ssl

how can i solve this?

here's some code in ConnectUtil.java:

```
public Response openUrl(String host, String url, int port, 
    HashMap<String, String> params, int timeout) {
Response result = new Response();
    // init PostMethod object.
Protocol mHttps = new Protocol("https", new EasySSLProtocolSocketFactory(), port);

HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.getHostConfiguration().setHost(host, port, mHttps);

client.getHttpConnectionManager().getParams().setConnectionTimeout(timeout);
client.getHttpConnectionManager().getParams().setSoTimeout(timeout);

byte[] response = null;
PostMethod method = new PostMethod(url);

try {
    int code = client.executeMethod(method);

} catch (Exception e) {
    logger.error(ExceptionUtil.getPlainStackTrace(e));
} finally {
    if (method != null)
        method.releaseConnection();
}
return result;
```

}

and the stack trace is:

```
ERROR [io.indertow.request] (default-55) UT005023: Exception handling request to /MyWebServicePath: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/httpclient/protocal/SecureProtocalSocketFactory
```

error happens when `ConnectUtil util = new ConnectUtil()`

thanks

Comment: Show your code and the stacktrace.

Comment: try changing comments-codec to version 1.2. At least that's the dependency the httpclient wants for version 3.1. Not sure if it will solve your issue though.

Comment: It is really SecureProtocalSocketFactory` and not `SecureProtocolSocketFactory`?

Comment: i changed to version 1.2 but still the same error. And it is `SecureProtocolSocketFactory` my mistake, sorry for confusing

Comment: maybe can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27517758/wildfly-8-1-classnotfound-org-apache-http-conn-clientconnectionmanager

Comment: i added the jboss-deployment-structure.xml and loaded successfully, but still got the same error message. my module name is following `<module name="org.apache.httpcomponents"/>`